# How to send multiple number of message to queue using jms

Tags: jmeter

Have a requirement while sending message to queue (tibco ems), it should be any random number between 1000-3000, how to achieve this in JMeter?

Will updating the number of samples to aggregate to `${__Random(1000,3000,)}` will work? Or there is any alternate solution for this?

[Config Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2IsE.png)

Want to send any number between 1000-3000 of messages to queue in every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, whatever number you will configured in `number of samples to aggregate`, that many number is going to pushed to Queue,

For example, I have given the value as 3 then it is going to post 3 messages to the Queue.

`Note: In this case all the 3 messages will be identical`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Jyoti, Sure will make sure to handle the messages.